# Watermark png keeps showing current URL

Tags: php, gd

I'm working on a script to put watermarks on images uploaded by users. Because every user wants his own user name on his picture, I decided to make a transparent PNG first with the name of the user. After that I use a simple watermark technique to merge the PNG and uploaded files together.

I got the script working, but it keeps showing me my current address every time a PNG is created.

This is the code so far:

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    $username = $_SESSION['login'];
    $filename = "watermarks/$username.png";

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        exit;
    } elseif ($filename == "undefined") {
        exit;
    }else{


    header("Content-type: image/png"); //Picture Format
    header("Expires: Mon, 01 Jul 2003 00:00:00 GMT"); // Past date
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); // Consitnuously modified
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); // NO CACHE

    /*image generation code*/
    //create Image of size 350px x 75px
    $bg = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 100);

    //This will make it transparent
    imagesavealpha($bg, true);

    $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($bg, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($bg, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

    //Text to be written
    $text = $username;

    // White text
    $white = imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255);
    // Grey Text
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($bg, 128, 128, 128);
    // Black Text
    $black = imagecolorallocate($bg, 0,0,0);

    $font = 'fonts/LiberationSans.ttf'; //path to font you want to use
    $fontsize = 20; //size of font


    //Writes text to the image using fonts using FreeType 2
    imagettftext($bg, $fontsize, 0, 125, 50, $black, $font, $text);

    imagettftext($bg, $fontsize, 0, 127, 52, $white, $font, $text);




    //Create image
    header( "Content-type: image/png" );
    //imagepng($bg);

    $save = $filename;
    imagepng($bg, $save, 0, NULL);


    //destroy image
    imagedestroy($bg);

    }
    ?>
```

I'm sure I missed something, but I can't figure out what.

My second problem is that I can not figure out how to get the text to the center and get rid of the white space around the text.
[image]

Please download the image to see what I mean.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are you sure you're deleting the incorrect image? I see the script just exits out on an existing image, also the incorrect image could be in your cache. for the centering, you'll want to use imagettfbbox to get the dimensions of the text and use those values to determine the placement.. (1/2 width of image)-(1/2 width of text)=starting position of text on image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not outputting the image. Most browsers will just display the current url when the headers indicate an image, but no data is sent.

Notice how you're providing a filename to `imagepng()`? If you read the PHP manual on [`imagepng()`](http://php.net/imagepng) it says it will *either* output the image if no filename to save to is present, *OR* save the image to the filename specified.

You need to either remove all the arguments after `$bg` to output the image, or after `imagedestroy($bg);` you need to open the output file at `$save` and re-output it.

Something like the following will stream a file to the output:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen($save, 'r');
while(!feof($fp)) {
    print fread($fp, 1024);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: `imagepng($bg, NULL)` would also have the same effect as `imagepng($bg)`, so by using `NULL` instead of the file name you can also use the other parameters (compression and filters).

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I needed to save the image in the background without showing it to the user. I guess I'll just show him the watermark in the gallery page and the problem is solved. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
// Merge watermark upon the original image
```

imagecopy($image, $watermark, (($w/2)-($ww/2)), $h-$wh, 0, 0, $ww, $wh);

For centering the watermark

refer this

http://www.nzwhost.com/article/simple-php-watermark